# isc-dhcp dhclient request address endless loop

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dhcp, isc-dhcp, dhclient

when a **Linux Mint 20 virtualbox VM** requests the network config to the home LAN router DHCP through **isc-dhcp client** with the stock `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` config file everything runs fine:

(BTW 192.168.0.1 is the main router - Sercomm H500-s - with DHCP server enabled while 192.168.0.98 is another exact router acting as bridge and DHCP server disabled)

```
root@PC-a01-01:~# dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xaf2ff163)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x63f12faf)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0xaf2ff163)
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1 (xid=0xaf2ff163)
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.wezYhIRa8t which is empty
bound to 192.168.0.123 -- renewal in 41497 seconds.
```

But when I try to ask for a specific IP address, the dhclient gets stuck in an endless loop:

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
interface "enp0s3" {
        send host-name = gethostname();
        send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.0.199;
}
```

`dhclient -4 -v -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x48fb1700)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x48fb1700)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x17fb48)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x48fb1700)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x17fb48)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x48fb1700)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x17fb48)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x48fb1700)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x43eff0c)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xcff3e04)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x43eff0c)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xcff3e04)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x43eff0c)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xcff3e04)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x43eff0c)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x4ab08339)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3983b04a)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x4ab08339)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3983b04a)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x4ab08339)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3983b04a)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x4ab08339)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x7e5bbe2b)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bbe5b7e)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x7e5bbe2b)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bbe5b7e)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x7e5bbe2b)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bbe5b7e)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x7e5bbe2b)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x2bbe5b7e)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x7e5bbe2b)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x32f5b011)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x32f5b011)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x11b0f532)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x32f5b011)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x11b0f532)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x32f5b011)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x11b0f532)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x32f5b011)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x77dca0a)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xaca7d07)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0x77dca0a)
^C
```

I've also tried the following procedure, while keeping `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` in its stock/genuine state without luck:

```
rm -fr /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases

nano -w /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases

lease {
  interface "enp0s3";
  fixed-address 192.168.0.145;
  renew 0 2000/1/1 00:00:01;
  rebind 0 2000/01/01 00:00:01;
  expire 0 2038/1/1 00:00:01;
}


dhclient -4 -v -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.145 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1935a408)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.1 (xid=0x8a43519)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xdf48dc0f)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xfdc48df)
DHCPNAK from 192.168.0.98 (xid=0xdf48dc0f)
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1 (xid=0xdf48dc0f)
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.RmsqemfUfM which is empty
bound to 192.168.0.123 -- renewal in 39093 seconds.
```

nmap scan to probe a single DHCP server exists in the network:

```
nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-18 21:38 CEST
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover:
|   Response 1 of 1:
|     IP Offered: 192.168.0.124
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 192.168.0.1
|     IP Address Lease Time: 1d00h00m00s
|     Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|     Router: 192.168.0.1
|     Domain Name Server: 176.103.130.130, 212.166.210.83, 212.166.132.96
|     Hostname: PWiFi
|     Domain Name: pperis.ddns.net
|     Renewal Time Value: 12h00m00s
|_    Rebinding Time Value: 21h00m00s
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.93 seconds
```

The following is the response I get after powering off the 192.168.0.98 router:

```
dhclient -4 -v -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
rm -fr /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases

# dhclient -4 -v -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf 
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:f1:e3:2c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe7d65802)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x258d6e7)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x258d6e7)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x258d6e7)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x33d20f05)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x50fd233)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x50fd233)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x50fd233)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x50fd233)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf3558362)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x628355f3)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x628355f3)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x628355f3)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xcd2ad06d)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.123 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6dd02acd)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.123 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6dd02acd)
^C
```

This is the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` config file for the previous output:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.0.189;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
timeout 300;

interface "enp0s3" {
        send host-name = gethostname();
       send dhcp-client-identifier 08:00:27:f1:e3:2c;
        send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.0.189;
}
```

Does anyone has the ability or an explanation to understand what's going on? I also would like to be able to ask for a specific IP address and if it's already in use get another one.

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: First you should disable the other DHCP server.

Comment: There's only one sigle DHCP server on the LAN which is the Sercomm H500-s 192.168.0.1. I updated the post so you can check it.

Comment: Why does your other DHCP server send a DHCPNAK then?

Comment: I just powered off the 192.168.0.98 and the issue remains the same, obviously without th NACK responses from 192.168.0.98. I'll try to dig in that direction but that's no the cause of the issue.